# CSS optimization to auto change class names

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, optimization

I am looking for a tool to optimize my website's complete build. I am using `SASS` as a `CSS preprocessor` and `Uglify` to create my JavaScript files, and a couple of more tools all tied together with `Grunt`. Also, the markup is in this case a single `index.html` file, but in other projects it's in either PHP files or in Liquid templates.

I am using BEM ([block, element, modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEM)) to name my classes and sometimes, that leads to quite huge `classnames`, such as `navigation__item__link--home` or even longer.

I am looking for a tool that automatically converts the final, built `CSS` files in a way that it changes the class or id names to something like `.a, .b`, but changes every HTML and JavaScript files according to the same method, so that correlated codes won't get messed up.

I want to keep my original project files of course, so I would like the tool to be capable of creating new files according to these rules and preferably, capable of using it with `Grunt`.

Comment: why exaclty would you care to use BEM in the first place? in my view, css preprocessors help mitigate the pain of unstructured, intransparent rules definition. if you don't like the style of a convention, drop the convention instead of introducing a workaround to that convention.

Comment: I love every single aspect of the convention and from a development point of view, not only is it optimal, in my point of view it's heaven itself. I am trying to separate development from deployment here and by the way, this sort of optimization can be helpful not only if you use BEM, but anyway, in this case you just win more.

Comment: You must have users with a very slow connection or an extreme amount of users to be worried about the length of class names. With a 1000 classes (defined or called) and an average of 20char reduction (which is a lot) we are talking about 2,5kB per user/per session with proper caching.

Comment: We did benchmark the potential advantage in our CSS file by manually overriding the classnames one by one and comparing that to the original file, and the results were significant. Compared to the original, minified file, which was 54kb, the new file, also minified of course, was only 36kb, which is a 33% drop only in the CSS. I don't know where your data is coming from, but I would love to see an actual benchmark result.

Comment: The benchmark would be different from file to file, so you can only do that yourself. My data isnt comming from anywhere. It was just a simple calculation on some numbers/guesses based on your question.
But i'm sure some sites could benifit from a 20kb drop in file size, but most dont. So I doubt anybody ever felt the urge to build a public replacement tool.

Comment: Well, I believe that any website always benefits from every single byte of drop in file size, of course the cutoff of where it begins to be worth of the work that you put into it depends in every case. In my case, 20kb shouldn't be crucial, but would be worth the extra work. :)

Comment: Please take into account that such tool can't be aware of classnames that are constructed dynamically in Javascript (or the used backend language). So, if you're doing this the tool might break something, or if you're not using it yet, this might block something.

Comment: how do you generate HTML and attach classes to your markup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a tool called [munch](https://www.npmjs.org/package/munch). It is a pre-deployment tool that does just what you are asking for.  It is a command line utility that you point at your view (html), css and js files and it will shorten class names and ids while still keeping them unique and keeping referential integrity intact between all of the source files.  There are also some handy options, like the ability to output a map file that lists what transformations it made.  The documentation is pretty straight-forward.

FWIW, I am not affiliated with the project.

Comment: Nice! This is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for this.

The sass and css can be done with existing [grunt-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) plugin and the javascript can use the [grunt-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) plugin.

While I'm not sure if there is a plugin that already does the custom uglification, you could easily write a plugin to do so. Grunt plugins are written in node, so it's pretty approachable if you're familiar with javascript.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that I am indeed using Grunt to tie all the tasks together. Unfortunately, I am not that familiar with JavaScript - or Node.js on that note - and I would trust an opensource, community-developed solution a lot more than my own work, not to mention that I doubt I would have the time to do that.

Comment: no problem grunt automatically setup the environment and folder structure for you then you can easily optimize your website. because for every changes you don't want to refresh your browser grunt will take care of it it automatically reloads the page for every single change.

Comment: How does that relate to the original question? I know all that and I am using Grunt, I am looking for a tool to integrate into Grunt and my workflow.