# How to uglify class names in NODEjs

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs

If you look at Google plus source code [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+queenstownnz/about) all the class names are like "Wa4 eR3 ..."

How do I do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Search for "obfuscate javascript" (and/or with a more refined nodejs context).

Comment: I think @Sahan means specifically minimising selector names across all web files (HTML, JavaScript and CSS) in a project. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959102/css-optimization-to-auto-change-class-names). There's a tool called Munch for this.

Answer (score 1):

try this one of packages

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS
https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2

and than

```
$ uglifyjs index.js
```